# when running a system test using capybarra, how can I test persistence layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I work on a rails app, where user can signup.

Once the user is signed up, I would like to check that the persisted user record matches some expectations, for example: the first name has been saved.

```rb
    it 'registers the user with the correct first_name' do

      visit new_user_registration_path

      within '#new_user' do
        fill_in 'user[first_name]', with: 'Foo'
        fill_in 'user[last_name]', with: 'Bar'
        fill_in 'user[email]', with: 'foo@bar'
        fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'password'
        click_button
      end
      user = User.find_by(email: 'foo@bar')
      expect(user.first_name).to eq('Foo')
    end
  end
```

In the example above, user is nil because the signup request didn't have time to complete yet.
I have considered different options :

1. only use `expect(page)` when dealing with system tests
2. play with `page.document.synchronize` and wait for user to be available
3. use 'workaround' using each example specificity (e.g: using `User.last`)

My understanding is that I should stick with option 1, but sometime user action have an effect that cannot is not rendered on the page.

What is according to you the best solution ?

Answer (score 1):

the way I do it seems to be reliable, if your form is creating a User, you can do this:

```rb
expect{click_button}.to change{User.count}.by(1)
user = User.find_by(email: 'foo@bar')
expect(user.first_name).to eq('Foo')
```

if your form is editing a user you can do this:

```rb
user = User.find_by(email: 'foo@bar.com')
expect{click_button}.to change{user.first_name}.to('Foo')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work : `User.count` will be still 0 the first time it is tested, and capybarra doesn't retry as it would when looking up for page elements

Comment: OK, you are editing a user rather than creating a User, I've added my method for testing editing